# Clubbing multiple rows in a dataframe according to a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In my dataframe there are various names in a row, I used `df['name'].value_counts()` to count all different names, now I want to merge the names which occurred less than 10 times and make just a one row out of them, I used the code:

```
df['name'] =np.where(df['name'].value_counts()<10,'Other Persons',df['name'])
```

but I'm getting error: `operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (111,) () (38973,)`

My teacher used something similar:

```
df['name'] =np.where(df['name'].isin([ 'Alex','Ram', 'Rishabh' ]),'Other Persons',df['name'])
```

and it worked perfectly. Please explain the difference in both the codes if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df['name'].value_counts()` creates a `Series` that has less rows than the df has.   This does not align with the required 38973 needed to assign a column to the df.

Your teacher's condition - `df['name'].isin([ 'Alex','Ram', 'Rishabh' ])` - creates a `Series` that has 38973 rows which matches the df.